# Why is my script firing on Mozilla when it should only fire on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

My script below is firing on Mozilla when it should only fire on IE? It works correctly with Chrome. The cookie notifies the user once per browser session that they should update IE (if it is version 10 or less). However, users on Mozilla are getting the alert aswell.

Code:

```
var key_value = "Cookie=true";
var foundCookie = 0;

// Get all the cookies from this site and store in an array
var cookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');

// Walk through the array
for(var i=0;i < cookieArray.length;i++)
{
    var checkCookie = cookieArray[i];
    // Remove any leading spaces
    while (checkCookie.charAt(0)==' ')
    {
        checkCookie = checkCookie.substring(1,checkCookie.length);
    }

    // Look for cookie set by key_value
    if (checkCookie.indexOf(key_value) == 0)
    {
        // alert("Found Cookie");
        // The cookie was found so set the variable
        foundCookie = 1;
    }
}
// Check if a cookie has been found
if ( foundCookie == 0)
{
    // The key_value cookie was not found so set it now
    document.cookie = key_value;
    if (GetIEVersion() < 11) {
    alert("You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer.");
}


}

function GetIEVersion() {
    var sAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var Idx = sAgent.indexOf("MSIE");

    // If IE, return version number.
    if (Idx > 0) {
        return parseInt(sAgent.substring(Idx + 5, sAgent.indexOf(".", Idx)));
    }
    // If IE 11 then look for Updated user agent string.
    else if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
        return 11;
    }

    else {
        return 0; //It is not IE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it. The last 'return 0;' was returning 0, obviously, which made the statement think it was IE Version 0: therefore triggering the alert. Changing this to a number higher than 11 fixed it.

Comment: You might want to return `false`, and test for that, or have a second function called `isIE()`. This makes it more obvious what the code is doing.

Comment: Good idea. I will do that and test it out. Thanks.

Comment: Works a charm and was definitely much better than using 999. Thanks.